# Unable to remove \r\n\t while scraping web data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, strip

While I was scraping html table from a website, I would like to remove all \r\n\t leading and trailing the `td.text` content.

Here is my code to so:

```
row.append(td.text.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').strip('"').strip().strip(':').strip(' '))
```

Without strip functon, the result looks like this:

```
[['BP / Age',
  ': \r\n\r\n           USA/ 2',
  'FirstName',
  ':\r\n\t    \t \r\n            Walker\r\n\t    \n\n']]
```

With strip functon, the result looks like this:

```
[['BP / Age',
  ': \r\n\r\n           USA/ 2',
  'FirstName',
  ':\r\n\t    \t \r\n            Walker']]
```

How could I get rid of the remaining \r\n\t ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to strip incrementally. Then you'll need to specify the exact order in which the characters appear, which is hardly likely to be the same for all strings, and the order has to be reflected for the leading and trailing parts.

You can strip all at once:

```
row.append(td.text.strip('\n\r\t": '))
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> ':\r\n\t    \t \r\n            Walker\r\n\t    \n\n'.strip('\n\r\t": ')
'Walker'
```

Comment: @JAY.Y If the answer helped, you may consider accepting.